# regular expression in Java (Spring configuration) with 2 specific characters in begining

Tags: java, regex, spring

I need regular expression which will start with 2 specific letters and will be 28 characters long.
The regular expression is needed, as this is in conjunction with Spring configuration, which will only take a regular expression.

I've been trying to do with this, it's not working `(^[AK][28]*)`

Comment: specify length using `{}` not `[]`

Comment: And also `[AK]` matches either `A` or `K`, not two characters,

Comment: You can also very easily do this without a regular expression: `s.startsWith("AK") && s.length == 28`. Don't overuse regular expressions, they are not always the best solution for every possible problem.

Comment: I need regex because this is in spring configuration. I accepted @assylias answer,

Comment: Then you should add the Spring tag, as spring doesn't always match regex like you would think

Comment: @dot_Sp0T No, you shouldn't just add the spring tag: you should edit the spring angle into the question and *then* add the spring tag. Comments are not part of the question, and adding a tag for something that is not in the question is not a good idea.

Comment: My bad, I will then edit in the Spring angle mentioned by 5er 31mins ago and then delete this comment, would that be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that the string should be like "AKxxxxxxxx" (28 characters in total), then you can use:

```
^AK.{26}$ //using 26 since AK already count for 2 characters
```

Comment: if I want length of the string to be undefined, what should be in the brackets? Is it a * ? thx

Comment: yes replace `.{26}` with `.*` for any string (including empty) or `.+` for a non empty string.

Comment: *.{26}* doesn't match 26 characters but 26 symbols, which can be anything from a-zA-Z over \d to .,-() etc.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T A character can be anything: character != letter... This is the official terminology, see for example [the javadaoc for `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef)...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count the number of repetitions use the `{min, max}` syntax. Omiting both the comma and max tells the regex parser to look for exactly `min`repetitions.

For example :

`.{1,3}` will match for *any* character (shown by the `dot`) sequence *between* 1 and 3 characters long.

`[AK]{2}` will match for *exactly* 2 characters that are *either* A or K :
AK, AA, KA or KK.

Additionnaly, your regex uses [AK]. This means that it will match against one of the characters given, i.e. A or K.

If you need to match for the specific "AK" sequence then you need to get rid of the '[' ']' tokens.

Therefore you regex could be `AK.{28}` meaning it will match for AK followed by exactly 28 characters.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is nothing specific to Java, nor is it that difficult if you have a look at any [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) (and there's plenty!).

To answer your question:

```
AK[a-zA-Z]{26}
```

The above regex should solve your issue regarding a 28 character String with the first two letters being **AK**.

*Elaboration:*

- **AK**[a-zA-Z]{26}
  > Characters written as such, without any special characters will be matched **as is** (that means they must be where they were written, in exactly that fashion)
- AK[**a-zA-Z**]{26}
  > By using square brackets you can define a set of characters, signs, etc. to be matched against a part of the regex (1 by default) - you can write down all the possible characters/signs or make use of groups (e.g. a-z, /d for digits, and so forth)
- AK[a-zA-Z]**{26}**
  > for each set of characters/signs you can define a repetition count, this defines how often the set can/must be applied. E.g. {26} means it must match 26 times. Other possibilities are {2, 26} meaning it must match at least 2 times but at most 26 times, or for example use an operator like *****, **+** or **?** which denote that the set can be matched **0 or more times**, **at least once** or **0 or 1 time**

In case you need it matching a *whole line* you would likely want to add *^* and *$* at the beginning and end respectively, to tell the regex parser that it has to match a whole line/String and not just a part:

```
^AK[a-zA-Z]{26}$
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` only matches letters but the OP asked for a regex to match any characters (unless he did mean letter)...

Comment: @assylias regarding the context given in their comments I assume him to mean characters as in letters. As special characters, e.g. /, do lead to other results in parts of Springs regex parsing